# how can I read embedded controller version from Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows

I found that, when I use msinfo32 command to read system informations. And I can get embedded controller version in windows 8.1. And I don't know how to read this information from windows command line.
Does anyone know how to read it?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've abandoned all hope, but could you let me know how you're accessing it in MSInfo32? I might be able to help, if you can.

Comment: This was abandoned I suppose? I'd really like to know how too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling here and looking at a way to get your EC (Embedded Controller) version, it's in the "information" section of your BIOS when starting your computer